Ballpark efficiency of a finned air heater
I am looking to spec an electric 240V in-line heater to raise the tempeature of air flowing contionusly at up to 400 liters per minute (14 CFM, 7x10^-3 m^3 s^-1) by up to 50C. I would like to keep the temperature of the fins as low as reasonably achieveable for safety (say up 100C), but also not to make the heater massive/giant. The dimensions and mass of finned heaters shown on the Omega page sound reasonable for the project:
https://www.omega.com/en-us/industrial-heaters/strip-heaters/otf-heater/p/OTF-1407-240
The heater will be placed in an insulated stainless steel box with air-in and air-out outlets. I am ignoring the humidity of the air and the variations in heat capacity, since 400 lpm and delta T=50C are the worst-case conditions, and in practice the heater will work at 1/2 that capacity most of the time. If the volumentric heat capacity of air is 1.2 kJ m^-3 C^-3, and if I am understanding this right, the required power is 1.2 * 50 * 7x10^-3 = 420 W -- correct?
What efficiency can I expect from a finned heater, provided that I leave minimal space between the heater fins and the enclosure as not to overstress the turbo-blower pushing the air?  I hope I do not need to spec a 1.5kW heater, but if I have to I will. Are there inhernetly more efficient heaters, with much smaller spaces between the fins? I mostly see them used in fluid-based radiators, not in resistive air heaters like the Omega ones above. I also do not want to use PTC heaters since I want to run a PID loop and achieve different setpoints (but I may not know enough to make this decision).
Thank you all in advance!

efficiency isn't the right question. All of the power consumed by the heater is going to end up in the air. It's a question of how the heater actually works. Most have heater coils that are made of a material that has variable resistance, so the hotter the coils get, the less power they draw. This is backed up by an overtemp safety switch. So you need a minimum airflow that will absorb enough heat to stop the safety switch from tripping, based on the power draw at the safety trip temp; and a maximum airflow that will still get you the needed temp rise at the full power rating.  For demand that varies by a factor of 2, you need a control system. And I would suggest a heat pump for better efficiency.
https://iseinc.com/SCRPowerControls/hdr/Literature/zf1_15-70_11-04.pdf

"Most have heater coils that are made of a material that has variable resistance, so the hotter the coils get, the less power they draw. " This sounds like a PTC heater which I would like to avoid. The heaters from Omega I posted in the OP are not PTC and have no overtemp switch. I will have to implement the overtemp protection myself as a safety measure.
